# Mix and Match PyQt4 widgets in a PySide UI

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, pyside

Is it possible to use custom PyQt4 Widgets inside of a PySide UI?

A little background:
My company writes many of its modern UIs in PySide, but its legacy UIs were PyQt4.

One of our older UIs has a custom QTreeView widget (PyQt4) that is *EXACTLY* what I need to embed inside of a QTabView widget in a newer PySide UI. Worth noting, the QTreeView also contains a number of other custom PyQt4 QWidgets.

Comment: No, it is not possible. But it should be trivial to port it to PySide.

Comment: Unfortunately this particular widget is part of (and reliant on) a much larger core package, and converting the source package is not an option. 

If I can't convert the source PyQt4 package to PySide, am I probably SOL on this?

Comment: The similarities between PyQt4 and PySide are entirely superficial. Porting is only easy because the syntax is virtually identical. If they didn't wrap the same library (and thus share the same API names), there would be no reason to think they could directly interoperate. As far as the underlying implementation goes, it would like expecting, say, Tkinter to work with wxWidgets.

Comment: If you can't port the source package, assuming your source packages aren't using any `PyQt`-only features, you may be able to set your environment up in such a way so that you don't need to port any of the code.  You can make a "PyQt4" directory that symlinks to the PySide installation.  You'll also need to do some monkey patching for things like `pyqtSlot` and `pyqtSignal`.

Comment: See what pyqtgraph does for example, to unify usage of PySide/PyQt (whatever is available): https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/Qt.py

Comment: Anyway, without more specific information about the legacy UIs all we can do is only speculate, but most probable it will work. Just replace PyQt4 with PySide and pyqtSignal with Signal.